# How to change the color of part of human body image using html5 canvas on hover and click

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, dom-events

```js
 
      var x = document.getElementById('body-male');
      var context =x.getContext('2d');
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,x.width,x.height);
      };
      img.src = 'http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/05/23__12_05_49/body_front.jpg23540994-0234-4ceb-ab8e-843eb92d1fa0Original.jpg';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="body-male" width="250" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
  </html>
```

For Example:
We have a image of human body, I want when user hover any part of body like neck, head, arm etc. The organ changes it's color to yellow and when I click over particular part it perform some action.
I don't know how to do this in Canvas HTML5 as I am new to this.

**Reason for the question:**

It is a part of my project where I want to take input from user by using human body modal.

For this I will need a image and need to know how to change the color of organs on hover and action perform by clicking on those organs.

Comment: have you already tried to solve this? you should post some code with your approach. It is also very unclear what images you want to use or how you draw the organs on the canvas

Comment: hi i have added the code and the sample image of the human body,please
run the code snippet and help me with the problem i have asked.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use KineticJS, a Javascript library, for the canvas manipulation

check out this blogspot:
http://dev.filkor.org/2013/04/14/create-an-interactive-map-using-javascript-and-html-5-canvas/

Demo:
http://dev.filkor.org/RiskMap/

Comment: thanks for those links,kineticjs really worked for me,i need to add lot of features in my model,and got lot help from this link  :)
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/

Answer (score 0):

For every area you want to highlight (neck,head,arm etc.) you have to create a path (or polygon) and every time when mouse hovers over the canvas you have to:
 1. detect in which area mouse is located
 2. clear the canvas,
 3. draw the body again and fill in the path corresponding to this area

For reacting to mouse clicks just detect which area mouse is located in.

Here is an [example](http://izhuk.com/test/canvas_hot_areas.html). For simplicity it shows two rectangles as hot areas. For your image you'll have to define your own hot areas which main part of job.

Comment: @Riktika There is an example added in the answer above. The purpose for this site is for people to help you with problem you're having with your code, not to write the code for you. Check the source of that example and try to implement it in your code and if you run into trouble, you can ask another question.

Comment: @Niddro 8 hi,yaa the example was added later,sorry didn't deleted my comment before...ayways i got the way to do it, thanks

Comment: @Igor thank you for adding the example,it is a grate help,although i got the way to do it by kineticjs.